# How to convert a persian text into a number

Tags: javascript

I have to calculate the Abjad value of a string. A user gives a text and it shalls return the number in Abjad table.

This is my code, although, I know it is wrong:

```
function letterValue(str) {
    var arrayAbjad = [
     {char1:الف,value: 1},{char2:ب, value: 2},{char3:ج, value: 3},{ char4:د,value: 4},
     {char5:ه,value: 5},{char6:و,value: 6},{char7:ز,value: 7},{char8:ح,value: 8},
     {char9:ط,value: 9},
     {char10: ی,value: 10},{char11:ک,value: 20},{char12:ل,value: 30},{char13: م,value: 40},
     {char14:ن,value: 50},{char15:س,value: 60}, {char16:ع,value: 70},
     {char17:ف,value: 80},{char18:ص,value: 90,},{char19:ق,value: 100},
     {char20:ر,value: 200},{char21:ش,value: 300},
     {char22: ت,value: 400},{char23:ث,value: 500},{char24:خ,value: 600},
     {char25:ذ,value: 700},{char26: ض,value: 800},
     {char27: ظ,value:900},{char28:غ,value:1000}    
    ]
    return arrayAbjad.find(value);
}

let str = prompt('enter string');
letterValue("str");
```

I wonder if you can help me.

Comment: Define 'wrong'.

Comment: You're getting an error message because you need to wrap the strings with `"`" or `'`. For example: Instead of `{char1:الف,value: 1}` it should be `{char1:"الف",value: 1}`

Comment: also replace `letterValue("str");` by `letterValue(str);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. First you are defining your letter. then you call search function and loop through every char in you **str**. for each **char** we loop through the defined letters if a value found you add the value it to **sum**. however this might not be the best way to go about it.

```js
var arrayAbjad=[{char:"الف",value: 1},{char:"ب", value: 2},{char:"ج", value: 3}]
function letterValue(str){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var charIndex = 0; charIndex < str.length; charIndex++){
      for(var i = 0; i < arrayAbjad.length; i++){
        if(str[charIndex] == arrayAbjad[i].char){
          sum += arrayAbjad[i].value;
        }
      }
    }
    return sum;
}

let str = prompt('enter string');
console.log(letterValue(str));
```

```html
بج
```

Comment: we want when user enter a text log sum of value of letter

Comment: Thanks
for example when i write "بج" the answer should be 5 but print not found

Comment: @somayehkhanbabaei try it now

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues with your code:

1. As I said in the comment, characters (words) should be wrapped with quotation marks (`'` or `"`)
2. You probably want that all the items in the array will contains the same properties so you could filter by them.
3. The `filter` method is getting a `function` while in your code `value` is, actually, nothing (Did you mean `str`). Anyway, you probably will want to read a little more about [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to understand how it works.

```js
function letterValue(str) {
  var arrayAbjad = [{
      char: "الف",
      value: 1
    }, {
      char: "ب",
      value: 2
    }, {
      char: "ج",
      value: 3
    }, {
      char: "د",
      value: 4
    },
    {
      char: "ه",
      value: 5
    }, {
      char: "و",
      value: 6
    }, {
      char: "ز",
      value: 7
    }, {
      char: "ح",
      value: 8
    }, {
      char: "ط",
      value: 9
    }, {
      char: "ی",
      value: 10
    },
    {
      char: "ک",
      value: 20
    }, {
      char: "ل",
      value: 30
    }, {
      char: "م",
      value: 40
    }, {
      char: "ن",
      value: 50
    }, {
      char: "س",
      value: 60
    }, {
      char: "ع",
      value: 70
    },
    {
      char: "ف",
      value: 80
    }, {
      char: "ص",
      value: 90,
    }, {
      char: "ق",
      value: 100
    },
    {
      char: "ر",
      value: 200
    }, {
      char: "ش",
      value: 300
    },
    {
      char: "ت",
      value: 400
    }, {
      char: "ث",
      value: 500
    }, {
      char: "خ",
      value: 600
    }, {
      char: "ذ",
      value: 700
    }, {
      char: "ض",
      value: 800
    },
    {
      char: "ظ",
      value: 900
    }, {
      char: "غ",
      value: 1000
    }

  ]
  return arrayAbjad.find(item => item.char === str);

}

const str = prompt('enter string');
if (str) {
  const result = letterValue(str);
  if (result) {
    console.log(result.value);  
  } else {
    console.log('not found');
  }
}
```

Comment: we want when user enter a text log sum of value of letter

Comment: @somayehkhanbabaei it will be in the `result.value` (Just where you put it in the array). I updated the answer.

Comment: Error:{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 114,
  "colno": 22
}
for example when I wirte "بب" the answer should be 4

Comment: I didn't handle when the search is not match to any item. I just updated my answer.

Comment: @somayehkhanbabaei, what do you think? Are any of the answers, answer your question?